# android - Textview's gravity doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem that I can't put TextView on the center of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="hojune.intelibag.Splash">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#404040" />
```

Please click the link to view my result.
[{my result}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEaVZ.png)

How can I make TextView put on the center of the screen? Thanks.

Comment: check my ans...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set gravity of text view related to parent, use `layout_gravity` instead of `gravity`. `android:gravity` is used to set gravity of content inside the view and `android:layout_gravity` is used to set gravity of the view related to its parent see [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) for more details

Make sure you have match_parent set for both layout_width and layout_height for the parent of the textview

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello world!"
      android:textSize="32sp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:textColor="#404040"/>
```

**android:gravity="center"** is use for textView text's center..and **android:layout_gravity="center"** is use for textView alignment at center.

Comment: I changed the code, but TextView is still there. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Hello world!"
  android:textSize="32sp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:textColor="#404040"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add layout gravity to your parent view like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#404040"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There are many stack answers available with respect to these type specific questions.please try those before your posting the new question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to change **gravity** to **layout gravity** if you are not putting TextView in any layout

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#404040"/>
```

else if you are putting it in a layout then try this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textColor="#404040"/>
</LinearLayout>
```